# Cannot connect to SharePoint 2013 from visual studio 2013 when creating an app

Tags: sharepoint-server, app, visual-studio-2013

I m trying to create a new SharePoint app from vs2013.I have the vs2013 ultimate edition and all the needed updates installed.When I press Finish in the process i got this message

[image]

One paradox is that I can access the SharePoint site via visual studio server explorer.But when I try to make a new project-app i got this error message no matter if the app is provider hosted or sharepoint hosted

Comment: I just had this issue. In my case I also had been working on an app that targeted a SharePoint Online site. Then, when opened a second instance of Visual Studio and tried to create an app that targeted a local SharePoint site, I got the error that you described. I tried changing the SharePoint properties as the message described and I got the app built and deployed but it wouldn't run correctly. I guessed that the issue was the other instance of Visual Studio so I shut both instances down and tried again. This time everything worked as expected.

Comment: Did you [configure your on-prem environment for app development](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179923(v=office.15).aspx)?

Comment: thank you both for your comments. wjervis yes I ve configured it.

Comment: This error can also happen if using VS 2013 update 4, create new App for SharePoint project (.NET FW 4.5.1), enter your office 365 developer site, select Provider-hosted app, select ASP.NET Web Forms App, select use Windows Azure Access control Service for authentication.

Comment: u need to install microsoft azure tools on visual studio

Comment: did anyone find solution for it?

Comment: what kind of Project/App are you trying to create ? 

are you just creating an app that connects into SharePoint ? 
or are you trying to create an Add-in ? 
or a Farm/Sandbox Solution ?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project, enter the URL as https (ex: https://*tenantname*.sharepoint.com)

Otherwise, if the project has already been created then select the app project's properties. Set the Site URL as an https site.

[image]