# "Cannot connect to the Sharepoint site" when creating Visual Studio 2013 SharePoint App

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I receive this error when trying to create a new Visual Studio 2013(update 4) Sharepoint app.

After I select "Provider Hosted" and enter the URL, I get this popup message:
[image]

- SharePoint Server is a on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine.
- Developing from a Windows 7 machine.
- Both machines internal to the office network.

I did not install the SharePoint server myself, but I have gone and created the App Catalog and followed numerous articles online about developing apps for SharePoint on visual studio and run a lot of powershell statements.

I am new to SharePoint development, and realise that this could potentially be one of a million things, but perhaps there is someone out there that can help narrow it down for me.

I have seen that there are similar posts but none of them that I have read have the same error message(which gives me hope that this is a specific error someone knows the solution to.)

Any help would be appreciated.

This may also help:
If, I do continue with the project creation after the popup error, I click ok. Then change the target back to "SharePoint 2013", instead of "SharePoint Online"(which Visual Studio changed it to after the initial error), choose certificate authentication, enter my certificate details, select MVC site...Visual Studio goes and creates the site....
After that, if I try to Debug,F5, the project, I get the error:

"The remote server returned an error: (417) Expectation Failed."

Comment: Apologies, pretty much a duplicate of [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117164/cannot-connect-to-sharepoint-2013-from-visual-studio-2013-when-creating-an-app/)  question. However there is still no accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your hostfile under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`

Add a line with `127.0.0.1 your.sharepointsite.local`

Btw, It's not the same problem as in the other thread - this is a on-prem problem.